# Error occured while refund payment in paypal

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to refund the completed payment in paypal using the id like "PAY-7TXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3RA". I got this id by making a payment from android paypal sdkv2. When i make the refund using that response id, i got the following error. Can anyone help me to clear this problem? What id should i have to give in the url?

URL : https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/PAY-7TXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3RA/refund

Error Response:

```
{
    "name": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "message": "The requested resource ID was not found",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "debug_id": "b34b00ad00d57"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sale you are trying to refund here is contained within the payment and has a separate ID.  If you GET the payment using the PAY-xxx ID, you'll see a `related_resources` field containing the sale.  Use the ID of the sale to refund.